# Brand new to SQL, looking to find total sales on a specific day

Tags: sql

I have the following:

```sql
SELECT [Sales_Line_Item].[Sales Date], 
       [Sales_Line_Item].[Quantity]*[Sales_Line_Item].[Unit Price] AS [Total Sales]
FROM Sales_Line_Item
WHERE [Sales Date] = #9/1/2020#;
```

Which displays:

[image: result]

I want to add the total sales together so that the result is:

```
Sales Date          Total Sales
9/1/2020            $6,276.00
```

Thank you for any help

I wanted to use `SUM(Total Sales)` someway but I'm missing an operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```sql
SELECT [Sales_Line_Item].[Sales Date], 
       SUM([Sales_Line_Item].[Quantity]*[Sales_Line_Item].[Unit Price]) AS [Total Sales]
FROM Sales_Line_Item
WHERE [Sales Date] = #9/1/2020#
GROUP BY [Sales Date]
```